# Clone/Duplicate Records in SQL Server with automatic increment of ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to duplicate all rows with `registry_id = 1` and the id's of the cloned rows should be automatically incremented.

When I execute

```
insert into [ZAC2].[dbo].[rubrics] 
  ([reference]
  ,[name_de]
  ,[name_fr]
  ,[name_en]
  ,[name_es]
  ,[registry_id]
  ,[registry_type]
  ,[parent_id]
  ,[created_at]
  ,[updated_at]
  ,[creator_id]
  ,[updater_id]
  ,[level]
  ,[inherited_rating]
  ,[has_children])
select ([reference]
  ,[name_de]
  ,[name_fr]
  ,[name_en]
  ,[name_es]
  ,[registry_id]
  ,[registry_type]
  ,[parent_id]
  ,[created_at]
  ,[updated_at]
  ,[creator_id]
  ,[updater_id]
  ,[level]
  ,[inherited_rating]
  ,[has_children]
FROM [ZAC2].[dbo].[rubrics] 
  where registry_id=1
```

I get the error message:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.rubrics' with unique index 'idx_rubrics_reference_registry'. The duplicate key value is (0, 1, RegistryPlan).

With `Script Keys as > Create To > New Query Editor Window` I get:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[rubrics] 
ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

With `Script Table as > Insert To > New Query Editor Window` I get:

```
(<reference, varchar(255),>
           ,<rating, varchar(1),>
           ,<name_de, varchar(255),>
           ,<name_fr, varchar(255),>
           ,<name_en, varchar(255),>
           ,<name_es, varchar(255),>
           ,<registry_id, int,>
           ,<registry_type, varchar(255),>
           ,<parent_id, int,>
           ,<created_at, datetime,>
           ,<updated_at, datetime,>
           ,<creator_id, int,>
           ,<updater_id, int,>
           ,<level, int,>
           ,<inherited_rating, varchar(1),>
           ,<has_children, bit,>)
```

Comment: What are the fields in the composite key?  And what field types are they? int? varchar? auto incremental? not null?

Comment: i pasted some output from SQL Server Management Studio in my original post. How can i get the ID field type?

Comment: What is the definition of your **unique index** called `idx_rubrics_reference_registry` ? That's the one causing an error - not your PK that you're showing .... obviously, with your `INSERT .. SELECT ...` statement, you're producing new rows that violate this unique constraint - you need to fix this!

Comment: What a poorly designed table.

Comment: @kermit, how would you design that table?

Comment: @StandardNerd Normalize it. Separate table for names & languages, registry, and levels.

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s you are absolutely right, i didn't read the error messages correctly. idx_rubrics_reference_registry has an unique constraint and therefor it could not duplicate the rows. I changed it (in fact my insert method with another id for the reference registry) and now it works. Thanks a lot!